# Set speed/animation of back button segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back, uinavigationitem

I want to press the back button from my viewcontroller and have no animation occur.
I replaced the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` and that didn't change anything.
I replaced the action and selector in the existing `backBarButtonItem` and that didn't change anything.
I know that that property is read only, but I don't know if that means you cannot change the property or if it means that you cannot change the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and add a leftBarButtonItem to your navigation bar. You can assign whatever action you want to it (presumably, popViewControllerAnimated:NO). You can do this in IB by dragging a barButtonItem to the left side of the navigation bar, or in code like so,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Zap" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(zap:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left;
}


-(void)zap:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```